# ABRT complains about failure of /usr/sbin/setroubleshootd

Tags: package-management, python, xml, xml2

On a CentOS 7 machine, I get:

```
ABRT has detected 1 problem(s). For more info run: abrt-cli list --since 1641301975
[root@my_machine ~]#  abrt-cli list --since 1641301975
id 4955357a1d46487319097d672270c4680d0722f4
reason:         libxml2.py:1:<module>:ImportError: /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/libxml2mod.so: symbol xmlLsCountNode, version LIBXML2_2.4.30 not defined in file libxml2.so.2 with link time reference
time:           Tue 27 Apr 2021 07:52:58 AM IDT
cmdline:        /usr/bin/python -Es /usr/sbin/setroubleshootd -f ''
uid:            995
count:          8489
Directory:      /var/spool/abrt/Python-2021-04-27-07:52:58-4894
Reported:       cannot be reported
```

and if I try to run that myself, this happens:

```
# /usr/bin/python -Es /usr/sbin/setroubleshootd -f ''
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/sbin/setroubleshootd", line 99, in <module>
    from setroubleshoot.server import RunFaultServer
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/setroubleshoot/server.py", line 70, in <module>
    from setroubleshoot.analyze import (PluginReportReceiver,
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/setroubleshoot/analyze.py", line 40, in <module>
    from setroubleshoot.avc_audit import *
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/setroubleshoot/avc_audit.py", line 39, in <module>
    from setroubleshoot.audit_data import *
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/setroubleshoot/audit_data.py", line 44, in <module>
    from setroubleshoot.xml_serialize import *
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/setroubleshoot/xml_serialize.py", line 45, in <module>
    import libxml2
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/libxml2.py", line 1, in <module>
    import libxml2mod
ImportError: /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/libxml2mod.so: symbol xmlLsCountNode, version LIBXML2_2.4.30 not defined in file libxml2.so.2 with link time reference
```

I'm not much of a Python person. So, why is this happening and how can I fix it? Is it a distribution bug?

I tried installing libxml and libxml-dev, that had no effect.

Additional information:

```
#  ldd /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/libxml2mod.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd63df6000)
        libxml2.so.2 => /usr/local/ge/opt/mc3/mc3lib/libxml2.so.2 (0x00007f03d24c1000)
        libz.so.1 => /home/intel-oneAPI-2021/oneapi/compiler/2021.1.1/linux/lib/oclfpga/host/linux64/lib/libz.so.1 (0x00007f03d22a4000)
        liblzma.so.5 => /lib64/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007f03d207e000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f03d1e62000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f03d1c5e000)
        libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x00007f03d1a5b000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f03d1759000)
        libpython2.7.so.1.0 => /lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0 (0x00007f03d138d000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f03d0fbf000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f03d2973000)
```

Comment: Please post the output of this command ldd /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/libxml2mod.so

Comment: @Alex: Udated the question.

Comment: libxml2.so.2 is pointing to a rather strange directory. This sounds like a version mismatch. Is the package libxml2-python installed? On a default centos machine, libxml2mod.so python module points to /lib64/libxml2.so.2

Comment: @Alex: I'll investigate why libxml2.so.2 is pointed there.  The package libxmk2-python is installed, but it's possible somebody has messed with things.

Comment: Something you could do before anything else is confirm that pointing to another libxml2.so will remove that issue. Search for /lib64/libxml2.so.2, see where it's pointing at and use LD_PRELOAD=/lib64/libxml2.so.2 abrt-cli list --since 1641301975 - meaning load the module specifically when executing the command. If there are no errors, then it's a version mismatch and libxml2.so.2 needs to point to the default system one

Comment: edit* LD_PRELOAD=/lib64/libxml2.so.2 /usr/bin/python -Es /usr/sbin/setroubleshootd -f ''

Comment: Will make sure of this probably tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

As @Alex directed me to figure out, the problem is that an entry in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` points to a directory which, in addition to a library I actually expect it to have, also has its own version of libxml2.so. The version incompatibility is what makes the Python-related process fail.